# Edge cant "reach" addin-part (SP online, provider hosted )

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have created a provider-hosted solution and added an addinpart (aka client webpart, aka app-part)

Im debugging this using a SP Online account
I works fine in IE and Chrome but on Edge I get an error message *"Hmm, we can't reach this page.", Try this
Make sure you’ve got the right web address: https://localhost:443xx*

[image: screen shots]

**Any idea why? Is this a debugging problem only or will is still be a problem on production environment?**

I did "reinstall" Edge using [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdMCkYnK1Yg), but no difference

Comment: have u found any solution for this issue, please confirm. I am also getting same issue. Regards
Vijay

Comment: Are there any errors or messages in the console that provide further details? What user agent string is Edge set to? (right click on page-> Inspect Element -> Emulation tab)

Comment: ...this was a while ago, I have forgotten about it. But I will revisit the SharePoint Addin-world soon, Ill post here if I start remembering :)